# Reset Password with devise gem 3.2.4 doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, reset-password

I am having a problem sending the reset password email to a user using the **devise gem** ( version 3.2.4 ), When I click on " Send me reset password instructions " the expected behavior is an email will be sent to the given mail BUT unfortunately nothing happen with me.

So I asked if there are anyone know what happened with me ??

Regards.
**routes.rb**

```
     devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

**views\devise\passwords\new.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>

      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="mb1">
        <%= f.label :email, "Your Email", :class=>'label block' %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :class=>'input-field' %>
      </div>
      <div class="mb1">
        <%= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions", :class=>'button button--primary button--small' %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Please show some code or working.

Comment: check the logs at your_app/log, there may be some errors there

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks :) When I checked my development log file I saw the mail written in the console because I'm in the development stage. When I convert to the Production I think a real mail will be sent to the specified mail.

Comment: be sure to have an smtp or a mailer on your server, rails ActionMailer is only a layer between the application and a real email server, try sending an email using the console on production to be sure it's working